# Moving NLog to it's Own Logger Service Project and Keep Current Logger Syntax

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, nlog

I have a .Net 6 Web API project with NLog configured following the steps at [Getting started with ASP.NET Core 6](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-6). I'd like to move NLog references to it's own Class Library. I was following an article on [ASP.NET Core Web API – Logging With NLog](https://code-maze.com/net-core-web-development-part3/). The problem is that this method requires me to change all my controllers from

```
private readonly ILogger<MyController> _logger;
public MyController(ILogger<MyController> logger) {...}
```

to

```
private readonly ILoggerManager _logger;
public MyController(ILoggerManager logger) {...}
```

Is there a way to get NLog in it's own Class Library, yet keep the current syntax that was built-in to the API?

Here's my current `program.cs` file:

```
using NLog;

var logger = LogManager
            .LoadConfiguration(string.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/Configs/NLog/nlog.config"))
            .Setup()
            .SetupExtensions(x => x.RegisterLayoutRenderer<BuildConfigLayoutRenderer>("BuildConfiguration"))
            .GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Debug("init main");

try {
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.

    // NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection

    /********************************************
    the 2 lines below are:
        1) the default taken from NLog docs and
        2) the code from the article I was following (currently disabled)
    ********************************************/

    builder.Host.UseNLog(); // 1
    //builder.ConfigureLoggerService(); // 2

    /********************************************/

    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
} catch (Exception exception) {
    logger.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of exception");
    throw;
} finally {
    LogManager.Shutdown();
}
```

Comment: You might need to implement your own custom logging provider which internally used NLog. That means in the main project, ILogger resolved to your custom logger which then NLog to do that actual logging.

Comment: You're right. I'll be looking for articles and any help on this. Would be great if you can provide a direction for me as well? Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider

Comment: I was just gonna add that url and say that I has already looked at this and not sure if I was on the right path. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Following the Microsoft article [Implement a custom logging provider in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider), I came up with the following implementation.

Created new project
Created 4 files exactly as listed in the article

### LoggerServiceConfiguration.cs

```
public class LoggerServiceConfiguration {
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<LogLevel, ConsoleColor> LogLevels { get; set; } = new() {
        [LogLevel.Information] = ConsoleColor.Green,
        [LogLevel.Critical] = ConsoleColor.DarkRed
    };
}
```

### LoggerServiceProvider.cs

```
[UnsupportedOSPlatform("browser")]
[ProviderAlias("LoggerService")]
public sealed class LoggerServiceProvider : ILoggerProvider {
    private readonly IDisposable _onChangeToken;
    private LoggerServiceConfiguration _currentConfig;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, LoggerService> _loggers =
        new(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public LoggerServiceProvider(IOptionsMonitor<LoggerServiceConfiguration> config) {
        _currentConfig = config.CurrentValue;
        _onChangeToken = config.OnChange(updatedConfig => _currentConfig = updatedConfig);
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName) => _loggers.GetOrAdd(categoryName, name => new LoggerService(name, GetCurrentConfig));

    private LoggerServiceConfiguration GetCurrentConfig() => _currentConfig;

    public void Dispose() {
        _loggers.Clear();
        _onChangeToken.Dispose();
    }
}
```

### LoggerService.cs

I did modify the `Log` method here

```
public sealed class LoggerService : Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger {
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly Func<LoggerServiceConfiguration> _getCurrentConfig;

    private static NLog.ILogger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public LoggerService(string name, Func<LoggerServiceConfiguration> getCurrentConfig) => (_name, _getCurrentConfig) = (name, getCurrentConfig);

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state) => default!;

    public bool IsEnabled(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel logLevel) => _getCurrentConfig().LogLevels.ContainsKey(logLevel);

    public void Log<TState>(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception? exception, Func<TState, Exception?, string> formatter) {
        switch (logLevel) {
            case Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace:
                _logger.Trace($"{formatter(state, exception)}");
                break;
            case Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Debug:
                _logger.Debug($"{formatter(state, exception)}");
                break;
            case Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information:
                _logger.Info($"{formatter(state, exception)}");
                break;
            case Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Warning:
                _logger.Warn($"{formatter(state, exception)}");
                break;
            case Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Error:
                _logger.Error($"{formatter(state, exception)}");
                break;
            case Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Critical:
                _logger.Fatal($"{formatter(state, exception)}");
                break;
            case Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.None:
                _logger.Trace($"{formatter(state, exception)}");
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(logLevel), logLevel, null);
        }
    }
}
```

### program.cs

```
using NLog;

var logger = LogManager
            .LoadConfiguration(string.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/Configs/NLog/nlog.config"))
            .Setup()
            .SetupExtensions(x => x.RegisterLayoutRenderer<BuildConfigLayoutRenderer>("BuildConfiguration"))
            .GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Debug("init main");

try {
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.

    // NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection

    /********************************************/
    // Call our custom logger
    builder.Logging.AddLoggerService();
    /********************************************/

    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
} catch (Exception exception) {
    logger.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of exception");
    throw;
} finally {
    LogManager.Shutdown();
}
```

I'm not sure if this is correctly done but it works. Not how I like it since I don't know the best way to log which controller and action was called so I'll put a hold on it for now until I research more.